# SwiftUI: change color of collapsable List view section indicator?

Tags: swiftui

I trying to change the color of the chevron indicator that appears on the section headers in a List view likest one shown here:

[image]

I tried to do that by setting the tint color on the list view:

```
List {
...
}
    .tint(.red)
...
```

That is not working.

How can I change the color of that indicator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't provided much code but some change with `accentColor` instead of `tint`

Comment: it does change using `.accentColor(.red)`. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The chevron can't react on any color changing modifiers.

You have to disable standard chevron and use own, custom, (behaviour of the List is the same), like below

```js
HStack {
    Text(text)
    NavigationLink(destination: Text("D")) { EmptyView() } // disabled  !
    Image(systemName: "chevron.right")                     // << custom !!
        .foregroundColor(Color.red)                        // any color !!!
}
```